# Could not cast value of type 'SCNView' to 'SKView'

Tags: swift, runtime

I'm following a tutorial to create a "tetris" game in Swift with XCode 7. I followed every single step in this tutorial, but I'm getting a runtime error:

**Could not cast value of type 'SCNView' (0x106c19778) to 'SKView' (0x1068fcad0).**

My GameViewController.swift is as follows:

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    var scene: GameScene!
    var swiftris:Swiftris!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Configure the view
        let skView = view as! SKView

        skView.multipleTouchEnabled = false
        //Create and configure the scene
        scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        scene.tick = didTick
        swiftris = Swiftris()
        swiftris.beginGame()

        //Presente the scene.
        skView.presentScene(scene)

        scene.addPreviewShpaeToScene(swiftris.nextShape!){
            self.swiftris.nextShape?.moveTo(StartingColumn, row: StartingRow)
            self.scene.movePreviewShape(self.swiftris.nextShape!){
                let nextShapes = self.swiftris.newShape()
                self.scene.startTicking()
                self.scene.addPreviewShpaeToScene(nextShapes.nextShape!) {}
            }
        }
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {     
        return true   
    }

    func didTick(){
        swiftris.fallingShape?.lowerShapeByOneRow()
        scene.redrawShape(swiftris.fallingShape!, completion: {})
    }
}
```

I already search for it on google and here and I didn`t find anything related to SCNView and SKView.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find the problem with my code. I instantiate the SKView as the view inside GameViewController:

```
self.view = SKView()    
let skView = view as! SKView
```

Before I do that, I tried to change the class of the view to SKView in the storyboard, but it was not possible.

I'd like to thank you for the revisions.